# ZFS magically vanishing available storage space

Tags: solaris, zfs, storage

Running zfs on a system, and my root partition has been shrinking with seeming no explanation.  I have now run out of space and can't find where it all went.

A simple df shows the following (You can ignore the TV filesystems, i'm only concerned with the root):

```
[root@SV02 /]# df -h
Filesystem             Size   Used  Available Capacity  Mounted on
rpool/ROOT/opus-2457409-2017-11-07-release
                        90G   6.6G        35G    16%    /
/devices                 0K     0K         0K     0%    /devices
/dev                     0K     0K         0K     0%    /dev
ctfs                     0K     0K         0K     0%    /system/contract
proc                     0K     0K         0K     0%    /proc
mnttab                   0K     0K         0K     0%    /etc/mnttab
swap                    11G   404K        11G     1%    /etc/svc/volatile
objfs                    0K     0K         0K     0%    /system/object
bootfs                   0K     0K         0K     0%    /system/boot
sharefs                  0K     0K         0K     0%    /etc/dfs/sharetab
/usr/lib/libc/libc_hwcap1.so.1
                        41G   6.6G        35G    16%    /lib/libc.so.1
fd                       0K     0K         0K     0%    /dev/fd
swap                    11G     4K        11G     1%    /tmp
swap                    11G    60K        11G     1%    /var/run
TV05                   168T    41K        11T     1%    /TV05
TV05/Media05           168T   155T        11T    94%    /TV05/Media05
TV05/OpenDrives        168T   1.1T        11T     9%    /TV05/OpenDrives
TV08                    54T    53K       2.2T     1%    /TV08
TV08/Media08            54T    24T       383G    99%    /TV08/Media08
TV08/MxSFX              54T    26T       383G    99%    /TV08/MxSFX
TV08/RMedia04           54T    51K       383G     1%    /TV08/RMedia04
rpool/export            90G    32K        35G     1%    /export
rpool/export/home       90G    86K        35G     1%    /export/home
rpool/export/home/open
                        90G   404M        35G     2%    /export/home/open
rpool                   90G    43K        35G     1%    /rpool
```

Used/available don't seem consistent...

Trying to track it down:

```
[root@SV02 /]# du -sh *
   0K   bin
  10M   boot
  10M   core
 2.0M   dev
 430K   devices
  58M   etc
 405M   export
   0K   home
 141M   kernel
  48M   lib
   2K   media
  24K   mnt
   3K   Mounts
   0K   net
 1.5G   opt
 174M   platform
 3.6G   proc
   4K   rmdisk
  10M   root
  23K   rpool
 1.9M   sbin
   2K   scripts
 5.1M   system
  12K   tmp
 1.5G   usr
 3.1G   var
```

OK nothing there... Thought maybe a snapshot, but that doesn't seem to be the case:

```
[root@SV02 /]# zfs list -t all
NAME                                                             USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
TV05                                                             156T  11.4T  41.2K  /TV05
TV05/Media05                                                     155T  11.4T   155T  /TV05/Media05
TV05/OpenDrives                                                 1.09T  11.4T  1.09T  /TV05/OpenDrives
TV08                                                            52.1T  2.16T  53.1K  /TV08
TV08/Media08                                                    24.4T   385G  24.4T  /TV08/Media08
TV08/MxSFX                                                      25.9T   385G  25.9T  /TV08/MxSFX
TV08/RMedia04                                                   51.5K   385G  51.5K  /TV08/RMedia04
rpool                                                           55.5G  34.6G  43.5K  /rpool
rpool/ROOT                                                      38.6G  34.6G    31K  legacy
rpool/ROOT/C_Backup1                                            1.24M  34.6G  5.61G  /
rpool/ROOT/C_backup2                                            1.33M  34.6G  5.61G  /
rpool/ROOT/napp-it-0.8l3                                        3.00M  34.6G  2.10G  /
rpool/ROOT/napp-it-0.9e1                                        1.66M  34.6G  5.61G  /
rpool/ROOT/nfsv4                                                  54K  34.6G  2.11G  /
rpool/ROOT/openindiana                                          18.3M  34.6G  2.02G  /
rpool/ROOT/opus-2457044-2015-01-31-install                      65.4M  34.6G  31.6G  /a
rpool/ROOT/opus-2457044-2015-01-31-preinstall                      1K  34.6G  5.61G  /
rpool/ROOT/opus-2457044-2015-05-19-pre15                          45K  34.6G  6.32G  /
rpool/ROOT/opus-2457044-2016-10-03-backup                         52K  34.6G  31.3G  /
rpool/ROOT/opus-2457409-2016-10-04-install                      15.5M  34.6G  31.7G  /a
rpool/ROOT/opus-2457409-2016-10-04-preinstall                     52K  34.6G  31.5G  /
rpool/ROOT/opus-2457409-2017-11-07-release                      38.5G  34.6G  6.57G  /
rpool/ROOT/opus-2457409-2017-11-07-release@install              4.40M      -  1.56G  -
rpool/ROOT/opus-2457409-2017-11-07-release@2014-02-25-22:01:25  6.64M      -  1.58G  -
rpool/ROOT/opus-2457409-2017-11-07-release@2014-02-25-22:05:33  84.6M      -  2.02G  -
rpool/ROOT/opus-2457409-2017-11-07-release@2014-03-19-23:25:59  58.0M      -  2.11G  -
rpool/ROOT/opus-2457409-2017-11-07-release@2014-04-12-17:55:40      0      -  2.10G  -
rpool/ROOT/opus-2457409-2017-11-07-release@2014-04-12-17:55:48      0      -  2.10G  -
rpool/ROOT/opus-2457409-2017-11-07-release@2014-04-12-18:13:10  1.44M      -  2.10G  -
rpool/ROOT/opus-2457409-2017-11-07-release@2014-04-12-18:14:31  2.17M      -  2.12G  -
rpool/ROOT/opus-2457409-2017-11-07-release@2015-01-31-21:55:47  15.3M      -  5.61G  -
rpool/ROOT/opus-2457409-2017-11-07-release@2015-01-31-22:34:52  9.18M      -  5.61G  -
rpool/ROOT/opus-2457409-2017-11-07-release@2015-01-31-22:43:54   362K      -  5.61G  -
rpool/ROOT/opus-2457409-2017-11-07-release@2015-01-31-22:44:05   362K      -  5.61G  -
rpool/ROOT/opus-2457409-2017-11-07-release@2015-05-19-21:49:36   227M      -  6.32G  -
rpool/ROOT/opus-2457409-2017-11-07-release@2016-10-04-16:11:30  3.15M      -  31.3G  -
rpool/ROOT/opus-2457409-2017-11-07-release@2016-10-04-16:34:30   936K      -  31.5G  -
rpool/ROOT/opus-2457409-2017-11-07-release@2016-10-04-16:34:42   986K      -  31.5G  -
rpool/ROOT/opus-2457409-2017-11-07-release@2016-10-04-16:53:00   112M      -  31.8G  -
rpool/ROOT/pre_napp-it-0.8l3                                      35K  34.6G  1.58G  /
rpool/ROOT/pre_napp-it-0.9e1                                      71K  34.6G  2.10G  /
rpool/ROOT/sv02-4-10-14                                           70K  34.6G  2.10G  /
rpool/ROOT/sv02-4-10-14-v2                                      4.17M  34.6G  2.12G  /
rpool/dump                                                      8.00G  34.6G  8.00G  -
rpool/export                                                     404M  34.6G    32K  /export
rpool/export/home                                                404M  34.6G  86.5K  /export/home
rpool/export/home/open                                           404M  34.6G   404M  /export/home/open
rpool/swap                                                      8.50G  43.0G   132M  -
```

34 gigs available but where, I do not know?    It's persistent after reboots and I haven't deleted any large files or anything recently, so don't think it's a process holding on to anything...

Comment: I don't know OpenIndiana/Solaris well, but I know a bit about ZFS. Take a look at all these filesystems mounted on / (rpool/ROOT parent). Is there any tool that snapshots or clones this filesystem? There seem to be a lot of GB wasted and effectively hidden because the mountpoint overlaps (or maybe it's just hidden).

Answer (score 1):

Given the posted data, this is your root partition:

```
... Size   Used  Available Capacity  Mounted on
...  90G   6.6G        35G    16%    /
```

From what you've posted, your root partition is nowhere near out of space.  Why do you think it's running out of space?

(posted as an answer because comments don't provide the ability to format code anbd therefore emphasize the important portions of the posted data)

Answer (score 1):

It's always a bit difficult to reconcile the output of `zfs list` and `df`.

From `df`:

```
Filesystem             Size   Used  Available Capacity  Mounted on
rpool/ROOT/opus-2457409-2017-11-07-release
                        90G   6.6G        35G    16%    /
```

This output shows you the capacity of the pool, how much that particular "device" (ZFS dataset) is using up, and how much free space there is in the pool.

From `zfs list`:

```
NAME                                        USED   AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
rpool                                       55.5G  34.6G  43.5K  /rpool
rpool/ROOT/opus-2457409-2017-11-07-release  38.5G  34.6G  6.57G  /
```

Here, we can see the root dataset is consuming 6.6G itself (38.5G including all its child datasets), which matches the Used column from `df`.  The 34.6G matches `df`'s 35G.  And the Size comes from the top-level dataset, which has 55.5G used by it and all its children, and has 34.6G free (=90G).

So your free space is available anywhere in the pool you want to consume it.